# Assistance with VB.net query

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

Here is my current query:

```
select No,
       (select count(no) from textvote group by no) /
       (select count(no) from textvote where no like '%Ginoo%')
from textvote
```

Table: textvote

```
No      Sender
Ginoo 1 9307895654
Ginoo 1 9566551234
Ginoo 1 9232235643
Ginoo 2 9225557878
```

This must be the result:

```
No      Total
Ginoo 1 75%
Ginoo 2 25%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind:

```
SELECT no,
       CONCAT(CAST(100*count(*) /
                   (select count(*) from textvote where no like '%Ginoo%') AS CHAR(50)), '%') AS Total
FROM textvote
WHERE no LIKE '%Ginoo%'
GROUP BY no
```

This query is working correctly in the demo below:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I want to achieve the result by this Ginoo 1 has 3 votes divided by a total of votes of 4 and Ginoo 2 has 1 vote divided by a total of 4 votes

Comment: select no, count(no) / (select count(no) from textvote where no like '%Ginoo%') * 100 from textvote group by no" give the wrong output

Comment: Update your question with the _exact_ output you expect and you should get an answer.

Comment: Ginoo 1 gets the result of 33% instead of 75%

Comment: Still the results is Ginoo 1 has 33.33% and Ginoo 2 has 66.66%

Comment: My query is working correctly using the data you provided.  If you still have a problem, then something is wrong with your data.

Comment: Yes I've check it my self. Ginoo 1 has only 1 vote and Ginoo 2 has 2. total of the is 3 only. My mistake. Thank you Tim